# Validate TextBoxes on a specific MultiPage page in an Excel UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, validation

So I am trying to make sure that all `TextBoxes` are filled out. However, I only want this script to check a certain page on a `MultiPage` page on an Excel `UserForm`. Below is the code I'm using but it is checking every `TextBox` within the user form rather than the ones on the specific page. Also is a picture to show you. I have circled the Page named "Box" which is also Page 3 which I want to reference when validating the `TextBoxes` and the `TextBoxes` of which I would like to validate.

[Snapshot of UserForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFmiY.png)

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim Ctrl As Control
    Dim Answer1 As VbMsgBoxResult
    ' Checks to make sure data has been entered into all fields on the UserForm Page
    For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf Ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
            If Ctrl.Value = vbNullString Then
                MsgBox "All fields must be completed before the information can be updated.", vbOkay + vbExclamation, "Missing Information"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ' Displays box with Yes or No asking if they are sure they want to save and close document
    Answer1 = MsgBox("Doing this will overwrite the previous data that was entered. Are you sure you want to do this?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Update Cabinet Information")
    ' Writes the new data entered into the workbook
    If Answer1 = vbYes Then
        Sheet5.Range("B1").Value = TextBox1.Value
        If IsDate(TextBox2.Value) Then
            Sheet5.Range("B2").Value = Format(TextBox2.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        Else
            MsgBox "One or more fields have an incorrect date format. Dates must be entered in this formay mm/dd/yyyy."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Sheet5.Range("B3").Value = TextBox3.Value
        Sheet5.Range("G1").Value = TextBox4.Value
        If IsDate(TextBox5.Value) Then
            Sheet5.Range("G2").Value = Format(TextBox5.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        Else
            MsgBox "One or more fields have an incorrect date format. Dates must be entered in this formay mm/dd/yyyy."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Sheet5.Range("G3").Value = TextBox6.Value
        Sheet5.Range("J1").Value = TextBox7.Value
        If IsDate(TextBox8.Value) Then
            Sheet5.Range("J2").Value = Format(TextBox8.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        Else
            MsgBox "One or more fields have an incorrect date format. Dates must be entered in this formay mm/dd/yyyy."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Sheet5.Range("J3").Value = TextBox9.Value
        Sheet5.Range("M1").Value = TextBox10.Value
        If IsDate(TextBox11.Value) Then
            Sheet5.Range("M2").Value = Format(TextBox11.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        Else
            MsgBox "One or more fields have an incorrect date format. Dates must be entered in this formay mm/dd/yyyy."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Sheet5.Range("M3").Value = TextBox12.Value
        Sheet5.Range("P1").Value = TextBox13.Value
        If IsDate(TextBox14.Value) Then
            Sheet5.Range("P2").Value = Format(TextBox14.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        Else
            MsgBox "One or more fields have an incorrect date format. Dates must be entered in this formay mm/dd/yyyy."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Sheet5.Range("P3").Value = TextBox15.Value
        Sheet5.Range("S1").Value = TextBox16.Value
        If IsDate(TextBox17.Value) Then
            Sheet5.Range("S2").Value = Format(TextBox17.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        Else
            MsgBox "One or more fields have an incorrect date format. Dates must be entered in this formay mm/dd/yyyy."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Sheet5.Range("S3").Value = TextBox18.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to refer to the Pages collection of the MultiPage object.  Therefore, let's say that the multipage control is named MultiPage1, you'll need to amend the line as follows...

```
For Each Ctrl In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(2).Controls
```

Note that the index for the Pages collection is 0-based.